# Responsive mobile web page - image not full width on iphone

Tags: css, mobile-website, responsive-design

I am currently building a responsive mobile webpage.
Header picture of webpage does not stretch 100 % of the wepage on iphones only(it's like 10 % white-space on the right side on the header) - looks good on android etc - what could be the problem?

http://makeitweb.se/mobile/

Comment: Am I missing something? I went to that URL on my iPhone and the image is something like 640px wide.  That is double the portrait width so it actually is too wide to technically be "responsive".

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004707/responsive-website-on-iphone-unwanted-white-space-on-rotate-from-landscape-to

Answer (score 0):

Give `min-width` to your page. Like this:

```
body{
 min-width:320px;
}
```