# mobile version full width 100%, remove space right side

Tags: html, css, mobile, meta

I tried to style `container` full width and height border line, in pc version it is ok, but test on iPhone,  there is a little space(10px) in right side.
But only in vertical mode will see this happen, rotate to horizontal is ok.

Why? How to solve it?

**UPDATE**
I tried add box-sizing:border-box not work.
And right now I'm using `overflow: hidden` ([Responsive website on iPhone - unwanted white space on rotate from landscape to portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004707/responsive-website-on-iphone-unwanted-white-space-on-rotate-from-landscape-to)) to not let user scroll to see white space, but the space between `container` border line and `content`, right side is smaller. So I set `content` `margin-right` bigger than left make it still looks like center.
But I want to know why and find perfect way

**Is it something wrong related I using meta tag? if I remove meta tag it is fine both vertical and horizontal mode**

```
 html, body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 .container {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   border: 10px solid #000000;
 }
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </dvi>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your container is 100% width and has a border thus a bit smaller than 100% width. Use `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: It shouldn't be fine even on PC, because UAs apply a `margin` to `<body>` and also the computed `height`/`width` of the `.container` exceeds the available space of `<body>` because of added border. Try this: http://jsbin.com/nocewi/1/edit

Comment: thanks reply add box-sizing and set margin 0 nothing change, not work...  I still can scroll to right see the space

Comment: Don't know if it will solve your problem, but you havet an error in your CSS: body{} is inside the html {}

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;` works trying use it like this `*{margin:0px;padding:0px;box-sizing: border-box;-ms-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box}` my concern is that trying use property hack on mozilla,chrome and safari

Answer (score 2):

Html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="solution" class="container">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:#000;
    height:200px;  
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 30px solid #999;
}

#solution {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

check below fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_siddappa/53grcpdv/,**

i hope, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your container has 100% width + 1px border on each side thus making it bigger than 100%.

Try one of these solutions:

```
.container{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container{
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
}


.container{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried each one but not work.. I still can scroll to right see the space

Comment: OK try adding this too: `.container{overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: I tried this before, but white space still in there just hidden so if the content inside container is margin:0 auto it still not be center. space between content and outline right side is smaller. I also tried move content margin-right  the container border line width , but I tried to find best way fix this problem and know why?