# White space around images only on mobile - wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I am trying to fix this problem - There is a huge white space around the posts and pages in mobile display. However homepage is absolutely fine.
[One such image is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l9bW.png)
I have tried display-x property. It fixes the problem of posts and pages however it breaks the homepage. 
I also thought that footer widgets were breaking this - but not. It was problem with previous theme too - can anyone help me???

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have this in the `<head>`?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Second, we can't see any code, so we can't help you. Do you have something long that's extending the page, like a large URL? That's usually the issue that causes websites to be extended out of the viewport.

Comment: I am sorry Tania! I should have posted some code sample. I have purchased a theme and with this new theme mobile display of my site is broken - i mean there is a lot of empty white spaces. I am not sure where and what to change. I am very novice to wordpress and css. I can only give my site id

Comment: I have used this - but did not work I have used this : 'html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

Comment: I figured out the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004707/responsive-website-on-iphone-unwanted-white-space-on-rotate-from-landscape-to