# Responsive Page on iPhone, Ipad - unwanted white space on right side of Responsive in landscape & portrait

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, safari

I have developed a responsive page, and have just noticed a strange whitespace margin on my responsive pages when viewed on the iPhone 4 , iphone6+ , ipad.

It scales correctly when viewed on chrome (PC , tablet), FireFox and IE.

I have used below `@media query` to remove that whitespace margin from right side of the page

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2)
```

but I failed to remove this issue from my page .

any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share URL. @Natalie

Comment: Do you have a [CSS](https://css-tricks.com/reset-all-margins-padding/) reset on your website? Otherwise it might be the default margin/padding of elements that causes the issue. Also take a look at [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8305036/1434964).

Comment: @AzharShaikh What URL are you referring to?